# Dynamic Lightning Web Component Lightning-Card Title

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, release, js, winter22

Over the weekend our org received the Winter 22' Release which impacted some of our custom LWC. I have a handful of Lightning Web Components that dynamically display/update a title. Before the release, this updated as expected but now it is not displaying.

**Current State:**

[image]

**Expected/Previous:**

[image]

HTML:

```
<template>

    <lightning-card title={title} icon-name="standard:opportunity">

        <lightning-accordion 
            allow-multiple-sections-open 
            active-section-name={activeSections}>

            <!-- If Opportunity Data is Returned -->
            <template if:true={opportunities}>

                <!-- <ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space"> -->
                <ul>

                    <template for:each={opportunities} for:item="opportunity">

                        <lightning-accordion-section name={opportunity.Id} key={opportunity.Id} label={opportunity.Name}>

                            <div slot="actions">
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:info" variant="bare"
                                    alternative-text="Open record" onclick={navigateToRecord} value={opportunity.Id}
                                    data-id={opportunity.Id}>
                                </lightning-button-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div class="slds-title__detail">
                                <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Type:</dt>
                                        <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail">
                                            {opportunity.Type}
                                        </dd>
                                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Product:</dt>
                                        <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail">
                                            {opportunity.RecordTypeId}
                                        </dd>
                                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Amount:</dt>
                                        <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail">
                                            <lightning-formatted-number value={opportunity.Amount} format-style="currency" currency-code="USD"></lightning-formatted-number>
                                        </dd>
                                    <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Funded Date:</dt>
                                        <dd class="slds-dl_horizontal__detail">
                                            <lightning-formatted-date-time value={opportunity.CloseDate}></lightning-formatted-date-time>
                                        </dd>

                                </dl>
                            </div>

                        </lightning-accordion-section>

                    </template>

                </ul>

            </template>
    
            <!-- If NO Opportunity Data is Returned -->
            <template if:false={opportunities}>
            </template>

        </lightning-accordion>

    </lightning-card>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getOppList from '@salesforce/apex/GetOpportunities.openOpportunities';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
    'Opportunity.AccountId',
]


export default class OpportunityOpenOpportunities extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    
    activeSections; //Default Open Accordion Sections 
    accountId;
    title;
    opportunities;
    error;
    wiredOpportunitiesResult;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
    account({ error, data}) {
        if (data) {

            this.accountId = data.fields.AccountId.value;
            console.log('Account Id: ', this.accountId);

        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Request #1 - Nothing was returned")
        }
    }

    @wire(getOppList, {recordId: '$accountId'})
    opportunitiesResult(result){

        console.log('Get Funded Opportunities Result:');
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.data);

        var opportunityRecords = [];
        var count = 0;

        this.wiredOpportunitiesResult = result;

        if(result.data){

            console.log('Data:');
            console.log(result.data);
            this.opportunities = result.data;

            var i;
            for(i=0; i< result.data.length; i++) {
                console.log('Id: ', result.data[i].Id)
                opportunityRecords.push(result.data[i].Id);
                count ++;
            }
            
            console.log('opportunityRecords: ', opportunityRecords);
            console.log('Count: ', count);
            this.title = count + " Open Opportunities";
            console.log('Title: ', this.title);

            this.activeSections = opportunityRecords;

        } else if(result.error){

            console.log('Error:');
            this.error = result.error;

        }
    }

    // Open Opp Subtab
    navigateToRecord(event) {
        console.log('Clicked! - Open Opp');
        console.log(event.target.dataset.id);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: event.target.dataset.id,
                objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    }

}
```

Please note this section in the JS:

```
            console.log('Data:');
            console.log(result.data);
            this.opportunities = result.data;

            var i;
            for(i=0; i< result.data.length; i++) {
                console.log('Id: ', result.data[i].Id)
                opportunityRecords.push(result.data[i].Id);
                count ++;
            }
            
            console.log('opportunityRecords: ', opportunityRecords);
            console.log('Count: ', count);
            this.title = count + " Open Opportunities";
            console.log('Title: ', this.title);

            this.activeSections = opportunityRecords;
```

Here we loop through our records and determine the Title. See `this.title`. We console.log that value and I can see that it is correctly being populated.

[image]

I have also hard coded the 'Title' value in the HTML Lighting-Card and see the title as expected, so I know that the `Lighting-Card` has not changed with this release.

Has anyone experienced this with the new changes or have any thoughts on how to resolve this issue? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to resolve this issue by defaulting a value into the `title` variable. So I did the following:

```
    activeSections; //Default Open Accordion Sections 
    title = 'Open Opportunities';
    accountId;
    opportunities;
    error;
    wiredOpportunitiesResult;
```

Then later one in the JS it gets updated `this.title = count + " Open Opportunities";`

Comment: [getter property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getter) will work better for this scenario and also consider using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string concatenation.